# Are there any good techniques for estimating effective sample size when the sum of autocorrelations is -1/2?

Tags: time-series, sample-size, autocorrelation

In the case when sum of autocorrelations (without lag 0) of a sample is equal to -1/2, one cannot use the following formula for calculating ESS (n is the sample size): `n/(1+2*sum of autocorrelations)`.

Are there other good ways of estimating ESS for stationary chains?